# SSH work from terminal but Jenkins can't connect

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, jenkins-plugins, cicd

```
- there are 2 containers in docker compose:
    - jenkins
    - remote_host
- there are also 2 keys:
    - id_rsa
    - id_rsa3.pub
- when remote_host is building id_rsa3.pub is coping into: home/a12/.ssh/authorized_keys
- when I connect to jenkins container via:
    - docker exec -it jenkins bash
    and try:
    - ssh -i id_rsa3 a12@remote_host -> it can connect without password
- but when I configure same Jenkins SSH with this id_rsa3:
    - Can't connect to server

SSH was generate by: ssh-keygen -t rsa -m PEM -f id_rsa3
LOGS from Jenkins show -> Auth fail and Can't connect to server
```

I try: ssh-keygen -t rsa -m PEM -f id_rsa3 instead of ssh-keygen -f id_rsa3.
I try: restart Jenkins service.
I try: connect from Jenkins container terminal to remote_host (it`s working)
I try: reinstall SSH in Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

Solution was related to this topic: Ubuntu 22.04 SSH the RSA key isn't working since upgrading from 20.04.

Way to solve:

- I checked logs on remote_host server and saw this error:

  - "key type ssh-rsa not in PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms"
- After I generate ssh-key in this way:

  - "ssh-keygen -t ecdsa -m PEM -f id_rsa3"
    instead of old one:
  - "ssh-keygen -t rsa -m PEM -f id_rsa3".

In my case ssh connect start working.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Dude, thank you so much! Been having this problem for about 2 days now.